# How do I change the default password?

Tags: 14.04, server, aws, bitnami

I'm trying to follow the instructions found over here:

http://wiki.bitnami.com/Amazon_cloud/Where_can_I_find_my_AWS_Marketplace_credentials%253f

It says to do the following:

The following approach only works for the administrator user for your application. Please replace "your_application" string with the name of the application that you are using and "mypassword" string with the password that you want to use for the application.

```
$ cd /opt/bitnami/apps/your_application
$ sudo ./bnconfig --userpassword mypassword
```

so when I enter say ABC to make my new password ABC (ABC is an example password):

```
$ sudo ./bnconfig --userpassword ABC
```

I get the following error:

> Error: There has been an error.
>
> No value provided for option --userpassword
>
> Use --help to get a list of valid options
>   ....$

when I enter:

```
$--userpassword --help
```

I get:

```
--userpassword: command not found
```

Comment: Have you tried `--userpassword --help` to see the syntax?

Comment: when I enter:
    $--userpassword --help
I get --userpassword: command not found

Comment: try entering singularly `--userpassword` what is the output?

Comment: `#--userpassword` the sysetm then says --userpassword: command not found

Comment: Do need a username and password there? if that's the case try entering `sudo ./bnconfig --userpassword username pass` replace `username` with a username if there is any and `password` with the password you have been trying.

Comment: Let me post it as the answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case try entering `sudo ./bnconfig --userpassword username pass` replace `username` with a username if there is any and `pass` with the password you have been trying.